# how to use jenkins REST to perform builds

Tags: rest, jenkins, polling, jenkins-api

The document indicates to perform a build with parameters, post

`job_url/buildWithParameters?par=val`

and to build with polling SCM, post

`job_url/polling`

Is it possible to have both, polling with parameters, if yes, what is the syntax?

Comment: Is your `job_url/polling` works? Or you just mentioned it like that?

Comment: Yes, polling job works. what I need is pollinng SCM with build parameters. the job_url stands for the actual job URL

Comment: which plugin are you using? for the polling url? URL remote trigger plugin? kind of?

Comment: Jenkins REST API:
.....
To programmatically schedule SCM polling, post to this URL
.../polling